# maintain session/connection between php and java app

Tags: java, php, mysql, sockets, persistence

A) If I have a java application which starts up and waits for socket connections on a specified port. Is there a way i could maintain a session connection in php after a user validates, i.e a persistent connection?

B) I mean, I'm trying to understand how its done with mysql and php. How does mysql or php know what the last opened connection was so you don't have to do mysql_connect after ?

C) Is there any benefit to opening and closing a connection on each page load or is it better to maintain a persistent connection?

D) If the latter is true in C, can you describe or give an example of how it would be achieved in a php --> Java connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) No, there isn't.

B) mysql_pconnect() works because of how the web server and php cooperates. The web server will typically launch a number of child processes which handles request. Each child process can only handle a single request at a time, and concurrency is achieved by sending concurrent requests to different processes.

Each such process has its own instance of PHP, which is reused for each new request. This allows **PHP modules** to maintain some state between requests. You cannot do this from regular PHP code, it has to be an extension written in C. There's no guarantees about this, though. A process can be killed and relaunched at any time.

*Sidenote: Of course, not all web servers uses processes like this. It's rather common to use a threaded approach instead. This doesn't work on PHP, though, since not all extensions are thread safe. Therefore PHP always has to run on a web server that creates child processes to handle requests. This mode (MPM) is called prefork on Apache.*

C) As I said, you don't have the choice. On a fast network, the overhead for opening a new connection is quite small, though.